# automating account reconciliation in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a spread sheet with three columns. the first column contains names of people. the second column contains dates. the third column contains amounts received and invoices paid for the date.

eg:

```
Name  date         amount
abc   1-jan-2012   2000 usd
abc   2-jan-2012   (1500) usd
abc   3-jan-2012   2000 usd
abc   3-jan-2012   2000 usd
abc   3-jan-2012   (3500) usd
```

i am trying to offset the invoices (positive values) against payments (negative value) received. if i use a lifo application then the net_value for the first entry will be 500 USD. the net value for the second entry will be zero.

can anyone suggest a way of automating this exercise. i have written an if statement but the condition does not hold when the payments are more than the invoices (a case of advances being received by the client)

thanks in advance.

this is how the final table will look like

```
NAME    DATE    AMOUNT  NET VALUE
abc 1-Jan-12     (4,910.00)  (4,910.00)
abc 2-Jan-12     3,674.00    (26.00)
abc 16-Jan-12    1,777.00    -   
abc 17-Jan-12    (5,477.00)  -   
abc 22-Mar-12    258.00      258.00 
abc 31-Mar-12    5,502.00    1,465.00 
abc 7-May-12     3,986.00    -   
abc 20-May-12    5,238.00    -   
abc 23-May-12    (6,861.00)  -   
abc 4-Jul-12     (6,400.00)  -   
abc 9-Aug-12     2,238.00    2,238.00 
abc 21-Aug-12    4,855.00    2,456.00 
abc 26-Aug-12    (2,399.00)  -   
abc 9-Sep-12     3,938.00    3,938.00
```

sorry guys for the confusion...

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Make sure the records for each person on a certain date balance?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - what do you want the end result to look like... Just show that and then we could create a formula to accomplish that...

Comment: the end result will be for example the 1st line will have a net amount of 500 the second line will have a net result of 0. then the third will have a value of 500, followed by 0 and 0. as i am required to use LIFO i am moving bottom to top.

Comment: NAME DATE AMOUNT NET VALUE
abc 1-Jan-12  (4,910.00)  (4,910.00)
abc 2-Jan-12  3,674.00   (26.00)
abc 16-Jan-12  1,777.00   -   
abc 17-Jan-12  (5,477.00)  -   
abc 22-Mar-12  258.00   258.00 
abc 31-Mar-12  5,502.00   1,465.00 
abc 7-May-12  3,986.00   -   
abc 20-May-12  5,238.00   -   
abc 23-May-12  (6,861.00)  -   
abc 4-Jul-12  (6,400.00)  -   
abc 9-Aug-12  2,238.00   2,238.00 
abc 21-Aug-12  4,855.00   2,456.00 
abc 26-Aug-12  (2,399.00)  -   
abc 9-Sep-12  3,938.00   3,938.00

Comment: Regarding your comment below and your new edit - aging invoices is completely different than reconciling them. I'm not sure why you would use LIFO unless you are dealing with inventory(which it seems you are not). It seems you are using the wrong terminology to ask your question. You are going to want to figure out exactly what you are trying to do before anyone on here can help you. From your math it is not clear what you are trying to do. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the values listed as actual currency amounts, and not the type of text in your example, you can use `SUMIF` to keep a running total of the account.

in D2:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2)
```

and copy that down. it will show a running total for the status of the account, also keeps note of the items relating to the name in column A, and not for all names.

for your example, this is the result:

```
Name date      amount    Running Total
abc  1-Jan-12  $2,000    2000
abc  2-Jan-12  ($1,500)  500
abc  3-Jan-12  $2,000    2500
abc  3-Jan-12  $2,000    4500
abc  3-Jan-12  ($3,500)  1000
```

Reversed format for a LIFO table - you put the first formula at the last cell (D6 in the example)

```
=SUMIF(A6:$A$6,A6,C6:$C$6)
```

and copying it upwards, giving a result that looks like this:

```
Name date      amount    Running Total
abc  3-Jan-12  ($3,500)  1000
abc  3-Jan-12  $2,000    4500
abc  3-Jan-12  $2,000    2500
abc  2-Jan-12  ($1,500)  500
abc  1-Jan-12  $2,000    2000
```

with the total consisting of the amounts on that line and below.

Comment: you would have to go from bottom-to-top though, to use a LIFO system, or you would have to sort your dates by latest date on top and use this formula.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i am using a LIFO system hence we will have to go bottom to top.

Comment: the end result will be for example the 1st line will have a net amount of 500 the second line will have a net result of 0. then the third will have a value of 500, followed by 0 and 0. as i am required to use LIFO i am moving bottom to top.

Comment: I can't see how you would get those answers. You may have to be more explicit on what you need to be totaled

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to balance for each invoice? If so you are going to want to have a seperate table with all of your invoices and the total/remaining balances can then be calculated for each invoice name/id.

I would probably just use a pivot table that I would refresh on workbook_change:
[image: Eg3]

At least that is how I would do it for a small scale excel reconciliation project. Hope it helps. Good Luck.

Another way you could do it - To create a list of unique invoices you can use this array formula entered with ctrl+shift+enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$20), 0)),"")
```

[image: Eg1]

Then you can simply do a SUMIF on each invoice ID:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,E2,$C$2:$C$22)
```

[image: Eg2]

Comment: yes i want a balance for each of the invoices. the final output will be like : the 1st line will have a net amount of 500 the second line will have a net result of 0. then the third will have a value of 500, followed by 0 and 0 . i am required to use the LIFO application which implies that i have to go bottom up for the invoices. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your math here(or in some of your other comments - why don't you display what you are looking for as an example in your question) - but it seems like Sean's answer is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: hey sorry about the earlier post. what i am looking to do is to get the outstanding next to the amounts for each line item... so the example should look like abc 1-jan-12 2000 USD 500 USD, the next line will have abc 2-jan-12 (1500 USD) 0 USD. the net value against each invoice is what i require.... i have a cumulative total of payments and invoices but i need to do an ageing of the remaining value of invoices and payments/advances as the casse may be... i have to use the accounting method of LIFO so i am going bottom top.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part - but why would the next row be zero - using your logic wouldn't it be 2500 (since the row after that is 2000)?

Comment: In addition, LIFO is used for inventory management - I've never heard of it being used for invoice reconciliation. So, I'm a little confused what you are looking for overall.

Comment: i have updated the initial question and provided the final results. i am trying to do an ageing of invoices, hence using the lifo method. the results will highlight my method of analysis.